# HTML Input on enter not clearing field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried multiple scripts and approaches on clearing the input field once enter is hit. I had one script work although it was too fast so the message could never be submitted.
I was wondering if there is any way I could delay it?

This is the script I'm using although it submits too fast

```html
  <input  class="chat-window-message keydown" name="message" id="InputMessage" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="....." onload="self.focus();" autofocus required />
   <script>
document.getElementById('InputMessage').addEventListener('change',function(){
    //somehow search for the term here
    //remove text
    document.getElementById('InputMessage').value='';
},false); 
</script>
```

Comment: what do you actually want? can you be more specific ?

Comment: I need the function to delay by one second so the form has a chance to submit

Comment: you can use `setTimeout` function delay any js code you want

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in JS called when you click on the submit button. In this function, call `submit()` on the form, then clear the field (with your code or the `reset()` method).